# How to count/classify specific records in a one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, grouping

[image]Thanks so much for your continued assistance. I'm hoping to create a list of counties that my staff serve, and a column for the number of Misdemeanor Investigations, and another for the number of Felony Investigations.
The Pending Charge and Court tables are outlined below. Court is the parent for Pending Charges and the CourtID Column of the Pending Charge table is = to the ID column of the Court table, i.e. JOIN vPendingCharges pc ON pc.CourtID = c.ID.

Court table:

| ID | DefendantID | CountyID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00035ed9 | 2a1e50f9 | Haus County |
| 000b2a8c | F3dc3251 | Saul County |

Pending Charge table:

| ID | DefendantID | CourtID | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9f78778d | 2a1e50f9 | 00035ed9 | 3 |
| a53a4841 | 2a1e50f9 | 00035ed9 | 2 |
| a9d2c5a2 | F3dc3251 | 000b2a8c | A |
| daf26cb0 | F3dc3251 | 000b2a8c | A |

Desired Output:

| County | Number Felony | Number Misdemeanor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Haus County | 1 | 0 |
| Saul County | 0 | 1 |

I too will fiddle with what you already provided which is great. Maybe by some miracle I get to where I want to go first!?. Thanks again for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery or CTE as a helper. ie:

```
select ChargeType, count(*)
from (
   Select case 
      when exists (select * from Charges ch 
                   where ch.CourtId = c.CourtId and ch.Class in ('A','B', 'C')) 
      then 'Misdemeanors' else 'Felony' end as ChargeType
from Courts c
) tmp
group by ChargeType;
```

EDIT:

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT CountyID, CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
   FROM PendingCharge AS pc
   WHERE c.ID=pc.CourtID AND pc.Class IN ('M', 'X', '1', '2', '3', '4')) 
      THEN 'Felony' 
      ELSE 'Misdemeanor' 
   END AS ChargeType
   FROM Court AS c)
SELECT CountyID, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ChargeType='Felony' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Number Felony], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ChargeType='Misdemeanor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Number Misdemeanor]
FROM tmp
GROUP BY CountyID;
```

And here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/fuiSO5Mg)

Comment: And that FROM clause subquery is called a _derived table_.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. Once I figured out that I did not correctly describe the relationship between the Pending Charge table and Court table. I was able to get this working correctly. CourtID of Pending Charge table = ID of the Court table. This works great. I'm going to play around with it a bit as I need to organize this by County, i.e. County A has 10 felonies and 35 Misdemeanors. Are there any simple tricks to changing your expression from a row to a column? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Haus, yes there is. If you supply some sample data and desired output for both tables, then I can give the SQL and fiddle demo.

Comment: Thanks so much for you're continued assistance. I've tried to edit the post to include examples of the tables, but the editing is not saving or I'm doing something very wrong. I cannot add the table to these 'comments' or format anything to make it understandable. If what I have provided above is not understandable, I will take another crack at it. Thank you again for your assistance!

Comment: @CetinBasoz I was able to add an image describing what I'm hoping to accomplish. thank you!

Comment: @Haus, I edited the reply with fiddle sample. My original answer unintentionally had 'A', 'B', 'C' anyway.

Comment: @CetinBasoz This is perfect! Thank you so much and this will be helpful as I will need to apply the same logic to other areas of the data! THANK YOU!